# Best materials for a long-lasting scroll

Tags: material-selection, fabric, medium-selection, pens

I'm trying to make a scroll to document life events. The important requirements are:

- approximately 30cm wide by 2m tall
- relatively easy for other people to sign their names on it
- can be rolled up and carried in a cylindrical tube in a backpack
- last at least 50 years with minimal deterioration, while being unrolled, hung on the wall, and then rolled up again at least 1-2 times a year

[Wikihow has a guide for making a scroll](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Scroll) (fabric lasts longer than paper; sew the fabric to match the size of the dowels), but no tips for making sure it lasts long.  An art store suggested I could use acrylic pens on canvas, but I also read that acrylic can crack and deteriorate from frequent rolling and unrolling.  [This forum also has some tips about calligraphy on fabric, such as the idea of stabilizing the fabric with clear acrylic first.](http://theflourishforum.com/forum/index.php?topic=933.0)

**What is the best combination of materials for this (type of fabric and type of pens)?**

Answer (score 7):

We actually have a good idea of which scroll materials last for hundreds of years, because we have scrolls that are hundreds of years old. What are they made of?

#### Parchment

We have [two thousand year old scrolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Sea_Scrolls#Age) written on parchment (as [required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gevil) for Jewish *Torah* scrolls). These seem to be mainly written using ordinary carbon black ink, but many (particularly Medieval) documents were written using [Iron Gall black ink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_gall_ink), of which many survive.

Parchment is expensive and relatively difficult to come by, but is still produced in small quantities.

#### Papyrus

The Egyptians wrote on [papyrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papyrus) scrolls, and we have several surviving examples including [some over 3500 years old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebers_Papyrus). Like the Jewish parchments, these were normally written using carbon black ink.

Papyrus is also expensive, but not as expensive as vellum and more widely available.

#### Paper

We have surviving fragments of paper with writing/drawing on it from the 2nd century BC, and we know that the Chinese made scrolls from this material. Chinese painting [normally used water based inks](http://depts.washington.edu/chinaciv/painting/4ptgtech.htm) for both paper and silk scrolls.

#### Silk

Chinese scrolls have been written on silk for thousands of years - the excavations at [Mawangdui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawangdui) unearthed silk scrolls dating back to the 2nd century BC.

Silk fabric is readily available (if relatively expensive), but requires treatment before it can be written on.

### Suggestion

Given the difficulty of acquiring and preparing the other substances, I'd suggest you look for paper. The specific type you're looking for is probably a relatively heavy acid-free paper (AKA *archival paper* or *museum grade paper*), which is specifically designed to last for a long time.

As for ink, since you only seem to wish to write and not draw/paint in colour, I suggest the ubiquitous carbon black.

Comment: This is the answer I would have started to make. Real world examples

Answer (score 4):

For such a thing I would use very fine 100% cotton, linen, or silk fabric (rough texture would make it more difficult to write on) and India/China ink to write with. No sealing.

It is probably not the easiest way to write for some people, as the ink tends to ‘bleed’ to a certain extent (I personally like the effect). Use a fine pointed brush and little ink if you want less ‘bleeding’ and give people a test fabric to adjust to the writing method.

I don’t know exactly how long these materials are proven to last without any special treatment but they surely exceeds 50 years in normal conditions.